# ggplot2: change order of display of a factor variable on an axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I use `geom_tile()` with `ggplot2` and discrete scales the labels are in ascending order on the x-axis and in descending order on the y-axis:

```
#some sample data
a <- runif(400)
a <- matrix(a, ncol=20)
colnames(a) <- letters[seq( from = 1, to = 20 )]
rownames(a) <- letters[seq( from = 1, to = 20 )]
a <- melt(a)
```

When I plot the dataframe `a` this comes out:

```
ggplot(a, aes(X1, X2, fill = value)) + geom_tile() + 
scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",  high = "black", breaks=seq(from=0, to=1, by=.1), name="value") + 
opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=-90, hjust=0)) +
scale_x_discrete(name="") + scale_y_discrete(name="")
```

and the coords are labeled differently for x and y:

[image]

I would like to have the labels sorted from a-z from top to bottom and from left to right. is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: You might also want to add a `limits = c(0, 1)` to your current `scale_colour_gradient` command - currently 1 is outside the limits of the scale and isn't coloured correctly in the legend.

Comment: @hadley: great thank you! that probably would have been my second question ;)

Comment: How to not order the y labels at all? If I have months for example J,F,M,A,M. It gets sorted automatically. Is it possible to override this default behaviour?
Thanks

Comment: @Roy as far is I can remember it is a matter of factor levels. but this may be worth creating a new question!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The important point here is the order of the factor levels. The order in the levels is also the order in the plot. You can use `rev` to reverse the order of the levels like this (note that I just reorder one column in a data.frame):

```
df$X1 = with(df, factor(X1, levels = rev(levels(X1))))
```

Use this syntax to reorder your factors as needed.

Comment: thanks for your fast help! But doesn't that change the x *and* the y axis. The x-axis should stay like it is. Or did I get something wrong?

Comment: You can change the order of the levels for each variable in the data.frame separately. Just reverse the ones you need.

Comment: sure! thanks - the product of the `melt()` command was the point to change! excellent and fast solution - as allways. the clarification helps in addition!

Answer (score 7):

For the cases where you would prefer to not modify the order of the factor in underlying data, you can get the same result using the `limits` argument to `scale_y_discrete`:

```
ggplot(a, aes(X1, X2, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_y_discrete(name="", limits = rev(levels(a$X2)))
```

Giving this output:

[image]