# Bar plot by group in descending order of categorical variable count within each group

Tags: r, ggplot2

Based on the data and code below, how can I sort the bars in descending order for each group?

Purpose: To show count of each `FF` in descending order for each city by district. This will then show me which city in which district has the highest count of a particular `FF`. Where `FF` = Flood factor (risk of flooding) ranging from `1` to `10` so, the plot will show the dominant `FF` in each city in a district.

Code + data:

```
df_sample = structure(list(City = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"
), District = c("D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", 
"D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", 
"D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", 
"D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", 
"D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", 
"D1", "D1", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", 
"D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", 
"D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", 
"D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", 
"D2", "D2", "D2"), FF = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-99L))

# Plot
df_sample %>% 
  arrange(desc(FF)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = City,
             y = FF,
             fill = District)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge",
           stat = "identity")
```

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12774210/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/18401931/3358272, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/44350031/3358272

Comment: By *"count of each `FF`"* do you mean *total* of each `FF` by groups of City and District?

Comment: @RuiBarradas, since `FF` is `categorical` so total  = `total count`. Like how many times each `FF` appears in each city by district and then arrange that in descending order.

Comment: I have added more context to the question.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Quinten honestly I am also thinking what'd be the most suitable plot for such a purpose. So, I am not entirely sure whether a bar plot would be the right way to do it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that this is what is asked for.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

df_sample %>%
  group_by(District, City) %>%
  summarise(FF = sum(FF)) %>%
  mutate(City = reorder(City, FF, decreasing = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = City, FF, fill = District)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'District'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

Following the [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74801411/bar-plot-by-group-in-descending-order-of-categorical-variable-count-for-each-gro?noredirect=1#comment132012506_74801620) below, here is a plot of counts.

The counts can be computed as follows.

```r
df_sample %>% count(District, City, FF)
#>   District City FF  n
#> 1       D1    A  1 29
#> 2       D1    B  2 20
#> 3       D1    C  3  5
#> 4       D2    D  1 15
#> 5       D2    E  2  9
#> 6       D2    F  3 21
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

And here is the bar plot.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

df_sample %>%
  group_by(District, City) %>%
  summarise(FF = n()) %>%
  mutate(City = reorder(City, FF, decreasing = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = City, FF, fill = District)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'District'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit 2

And here is the plot with the counts over the bars and the values of `FF` in the middle of the bars. This is probably too complicated but it works.

```r
df_sample %>%
  mutate(FF = factor(FF)) %>%
  group_by(District, City, FF) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  group_by(District) %>%
  mutate(
    tmp = as.integer(factor(n)),
    City = reorder(City, tmp, decreasing = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  select(-tmp) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = City, n, fill = District)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), vjust = -1) +
  geom_text(aes(y = n/2, label = FF)) +
  # geom_label(aes(y = n/2, label = FF), fill = "white") +
  ylim(0, 31)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'District', 'City'. You can override using
#> the `.groups` argument.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Instead of `sum` I am interested in `count`

Comment: Oh, so now the count is on the `y-axis`?

Comment: @Ed_Gravy Yes, just a moment, will edit with the actual values. Done.

Comment: Cool thanks now how can I label (or something  similar) to also show the total count (n) of each `FF` in the plot as well?

Comment: @Ed_Gravy Just add `geom_text(aes(label = FF), vjust=-1)` at the end, after `geom_col`.

Comment: Awesome, one last question, how can I also add the `FF` i.e. `1`, `2` and `3` as a label for each respective bar?

Comment: @Ed_Gravy With `geom_text` or `geom_label`. But with `vjust = 0.5` to put them in the middle of the bars. The main difference is that `geom_label` puts the labels in a (white) rectangle.

Comment: But, now `FF = n()` (so what variable will I put in `geom_text()`?) so, shouldn't `count` be in a column say `N` and leave `FF` as it is. This way  both `count` and `FF` labels can be added to the plot, right?

Comment: @Ed_Gravy Done, see now, edit 2. I bet that there's simpler but it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can reorder `City` as factor

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

df_sample %>% 
  mutate(City = fct_rev(fct_reorder2(City,FF,District))) %>%
  # arrange(desc(FF)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = City,
             y = FF,
             fill = District)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge",
           stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I meant descending order by count of  each `FF`