# Switching columns within a geom_col() plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-col

I am attempting to switch the plotted bars so the first column is for Budgeted and the second column in for Actual. Any help is much appreciated.

[image: Picture]

This is my code.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

Mississppi <-as.data.frame(R_test_8)
head(Mississppi)


ggplot() + geom_col(data = Mississppi, aes( x = Ship, y = Mandays , fill = Type), position = "dodge") +  geom_point() +
 scale_y_continuous(labels = label_number (suffix = " K", scale = 1e-3), limits = c(0, 400000), breaks = seq(0, 400000, by = 50000)) + geom_hline(yintercept = 200000, color = "#7c7d81", linetype = 2) + scale_fill_manual(values = c("#6b9bb1", "#102031")) +  geom_point() +
  theme_classic() + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank()) + ggtitle("Days of Labor (Thousands)")
```

Comment: Please make your question reproducible: include the output of `dput(R_test_8)` in the question.

Comment: `Mississppi2 <- Mississppi |> mutate(Type = fct_rev(Type))` and then use Mississppi2. That will make the Type variable be a factor that is in the opposite order of its current default alphabetical order.

Comment: just about (or perhaps "all"?) questions on SO that ask about "order of axis", "order of plots", or "order of legend" are resolved with the use of `factor` and using its `levels=` argument

Comment: see ggplot2/axis-order: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3253641/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12774210/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/18401931/3358272; ordering with groups https://stackoverflow.com/q/44350031/3358272

Comment: Welcome to SO, tatertot2! This question will be closed as a duplicate, please look at the links I provided and learn how to apply it to your data (which we don't have). If after you do that you still cannot figure it out, please make this question [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269) by [edit]ing it and including sample data (perhaps using `dput` or `data.frame`, see that link), and show the updated code with any warnings/errors. Once that's done, @-ping me and we'll sort out what is different or such. Thanks and good luck!