# How can I manually place the NA entry in R ggplot2 discrete map legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a map of discrete-valued polygons using ggplot2 and a "YlGn" color scheme, where the highest category appears at the top of the legend (and has the darkest green color) and the lowest category appears at the bottom. I am able to get close to what I want, but the "NA" legend entry appears at the top of the legend, rather than the bottom, which is where I would like it.

To get my current output, I am doing the following:

```
or <- or %>% 
  mutate(nonirr_rent_class = cut(nonirr_crop_rent, breaks = c(0, 50, 100, 150, 200), include.lowest = T)) 

nonirr_breaks<-c("0-50", "50-100", "100-150", "150-200")


(
  nonirr_rent <- ggplot(data = or) +
    geom_sf(aes(fill = nonirr_rent_class)) +
    labs(fill = "$/acre") +
    ggtitle("Non-irrigated cropland rent, 2023") +
    theme_void() +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 14)) +
    scale_fill_discrete_sequential(palette = "YlGn",labels = nonirr_breaks, na.value="gray", guide = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))

)
```

Here is the output I'm receiving. Again the only thing I would like to change is to have the NA entry appear at the bottom, rather than the top, of the legend.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2WGi.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, DDB! Every question on SO and the [tag:ggplot2] tag that asks about order of facets, axis labels, and legend components has been resolved with the use of `factor`s. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3253641/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12774210/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/18401931/3358272.

Comment: Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (you have a great start, but please be explicit about non-base packages other than `ggplot2`), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to manually reverse the legend instead of relying on `guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)`. To this end reverse the `breaks` and `labels` and put the `NA` value at the end.

Using a minimal reproducible example base on the `nc` shape file from the `sf` package:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(colorspace)

or <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
or$AREA <- 1000 * or$AREA
names(or)[1] <- "nonirr_crop_rent"

or$nonirr_rent_class <- cut(or$nonirr_crop_rent,
  breaks = c(0, 50, 100, 150, 200), include.lowest = TRUE
)

nonirr_breaks <- c("0-50", "50-100", "100-150", "150-200")

ggplot(data = or) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = nonirr_rent_class)) +
  labs(fill = "$/acre") +
  ggtitle("Non-irrigated cropland rent, 2023") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 14)) +
  colorspace::scale_fill_discrete_sequential(
    palette = "YlGn",
    labels = rev(nonirr_breaks), 
    na.value = "gray",
    breaks = ~ c(rev(.x[!is.na(.x)]), NA)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly for my purposes.